# Rails3: How to get a checkbox to add / remove fields from a form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form to create events.  If an event is repeating, the user can click a checkbox which will load the additional form fields dealing with repeating tasks.

How can I set up the checkbox so that when its clicked the form elements are loaded, and when it's unchecked the form elements are not shown (or removed if need be)?

Comment: Don't you just put a handler on the click event for the checkbox and either hide or show the relevant components?  Typically you would do this in the $(document).ready event.  If this is what your problem is, I can try to add some code and create an answer...

Comment: You're right, that's the simplest solution.  I was trying to dynamically load a partial containing the form elements.  It's much easier to just load the entire form and hide/unhide form elements.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Definitely much easier.  :)  Do you need me to update some sample code, or are you good?  You can answer your own question to close it if all is well.

Comment: If you want credit (points) feel free to post it and I'll up-vote it.  Otherwise I can code it later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Hide div
  $(".hidden_fields").css("display","none");

  // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/ class 'toggle_hidden_fields'
  $(".toggle_hidden_fields").click(function(){
    if ($(".toggle_hidden_fields").is(":checked")) {
      // Show the hidden div
      $(".hidden_fields").show("fast");
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise, hide it
      $(".hidden_fields").hide("fast");
    }
  });
});
```

Modified from: http://iamzed.com/2006/12/14/using-jquery-to-show-hide-form-elements-based-on-a-checkbox-selection/

*Tip of the hat to Marc Talbot